# Can't boot: "mdadm: CREATE group disk not found"

Tags: boot, encryption, mdadm

After running `apt-get upgrade` yesterday and shutting down, I'm no longer able to boot Ubuntu 15.

The last several lines I see during boot are:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
```

My hard disk is encrypted, so normally I would get a Passphrase prompt here. However, after a little while, I just get:

```
mdadm: CREATE group disk not found
```

This message repeats ad infinitum and I'm not able to boot. Same with recovery mode.

I found a few threads about this error, but no solution yet. What can I do to diagnose and fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Fairly sure this isn't grub related.

Comment: Say can you mount the disk in another system, decrypt it and check whether `cryptsetup` is still installed? Should be in `/sbin/cryptsetup`.

Comment: Thanks, should I just remove the grub2 tag, then? I don't have access to another machine - would your suggestion work from an external disk with Ubuntu netinstall on it, for example?

Comment: Yes, as long as it has `cryptsetup` (the standard linux encryption tool). And I think it does.

Comment: Thanks, Wolfer. That's definitely a good step to try later today. I'll look for instructions for unlocking the disk from a live boot. What should I do if `cryptsetup` is not there? I suspect some dependency was removed during the `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Unlocking should go something like `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen <partition> <alias>` alias is arbitrary, but your data will show up under `/dev/mapper/<alias>`. If cryptsetup got deleted then you should reinstall it, to do that you will need to create a chroot environment from the unlocked disk (and the boot partition) and then install it in that, but I'll detail it as an answer if that's the case. So ping back on `cryptsetup`.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `cryptsetup` is there, in `/mnt/sbin/`.

Comment: Please post the contents of the `/etc/default/grub` file from the unbootable system, it likely has some stuff missing.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner - I ended up re-imaging the machine. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: I noticed that this line was a part of my `mdadm.conf` file: `CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes`.  I'm thinking the `group=disk` is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is generated by the initramfs script that finds and mounts the root fs.

I've experienced this message before and it turned out to be caused by updating the initramfs from a live cd.

The thing was that I had an encrypted root, and when opening the luks volume from the live cd I didn't use the same name that was in my crypttab.

So, I booted the live cd and did:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md1 md1
vgchange -ay
mount /dev/vgmain/lvroot /mnt/custom
<... mount dev et. al ...>
chroot /mnt/custom
<... fix something ...>
update-initramfs -u
exit
umount /mnt/custom && vgchange -an && cryptsetup luksClose md1
```

The `update-initramfs -u` did warn about `cryptsetup: WARNING: invalid line in /etc/crypttab -` but at first I didn't deem it important.

After some failed attempts to boot it hit me: my crypttab had `md1_crypt` for the luks volume, but when I updated the initramfs it saw `md1` so it went with that. From within the boot scripts `md1` was not available as a luks volume.

So I booted my livecd again and corrected it:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md1 md1_crypt
vgchange -ay
mount /dev/vgmain/lvroot /mnt/custom
<... mount dev et. al ...>
chroot /mnt/custom
update-initramfs -u
exit
umount /mnt/custom
vgchange -an
cryptsetup luksClose md1_crypt
```

I've looked through the initramfs-tools scripts, but I couldn't find the exact spot where this went wrong, so I assume it was just some weird interaction between cryptsetup, mdadm and lvm.

On another debian host I had a similar issue*, except this time without crypttools or lvm involved, and I was able to work around it by changing my `mdadm.conf` from `/dev/md/n` device paths to `/dev/mdn`. On this ocassion, the issue only presented itself while the array was rebuilding and not when everything was normal.

Perhaps someone more familiar with the inner workings of initramfs-tools can figure this out.

<sub>* the debian host also showed a message like `incrementally starting raid arrays` after a few `CREATE group disk not found`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**gnp**'s answer was pretty good and definitely pointed me in the right direction (my problem was caused by a broken `cryptroot` setup). However, it wasn't quite sufficient to debug the problem)

1. This can be due to `cryptsetup` not mapping encrypted volume. This means that initramfs does not have and `lvm` volume to mount, if you are using and encrypted lvm physical group (the default encrypted ubuntu install)
2. For generally debugging this sort of problem, you want to understand initramfs and update-initramfs (google, then I would insert links by stackexchange won't let me)
3. To get more debugging output you can edit your boot options in grub (by pressing `e` over a valid option), you should remove the splash and quiet options. If this is not sufficient you can use `break=premount` as described here: https://wiki.debian.org/InitramfsDebug, to drop into an interactive shell and see what is going on. The script that was causing problems here was called cryptroot.
4. To understand what is going on in the generation of initramfs scripts, you can look at the files in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks` and `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts`, the former is run on a full working system to generate configuration for the latter. You might try adding `set -x` flags to these scripts for debugging.

In my particular case, I had problems correcting this from a boot disk with `chroot` because `lvm` tools where not returning the correct results inside the jail. I needed to mount in a number of things to work around this. I also had to ensure that the luks volume was mapped with the correct name (It needed to match up with the value in `crypttab`, and the helpful graphical interface was picking quite a bad name.

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md1 md1_crypt
mount --bind /sys /mnt/encrypted-root/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/encrypted-root/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/encrypted-root/proc
chroot /mnt/encrypted-root
update-inintramfs -c -k all
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with race conditions when mdadm builds disk arrays. You may have to play with delays in the pre-mount scripts to allow all the arrays to be built. I have set up a nested RAID for /boot because grub cannot deal with RAID10 and the second level mirror RAID1 does not get normally built by mdadm. So I have had to put mdadm --assemble /dev/md/boot into a pre-mount script.

Your situation maybe different but I think my experience gives a clue.